# How to query the current consumed weight in an extrinsic?

Tags: weight, block, frame-system, finalization

Hi Substrate Community,

is there any way to get the current block weight? This is especially useful, when deciding in `on_finalize` if there is space left to put in some logic. I know, that `on_finalize` is guaranteed to run, but I would only run if a block is not full.

How can I manage to do this with Substrate?

I already tried to look into the `transaction_payment` and `frame_system` pallet. I could find a [`BlockWeights` struct](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/fd549573b2fffd620d9f2fcea76edab1cdabc62f/frame/system/src/limits.rs#L198-L206), but it hasn't the current block weight inside it.

Comment: Did you have a look at `on_idle`? It gets the remaining weight passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_idle` hook is probably closer to what you are looking for.
It gets the remaining weight passed into it like this:

```rust
fn on_idle(block: T::BlockNumber, remaining: Weight) -> Weight
```

This happens after all normal transactions and before `on_finalize`.